# doxygen alias to struct, class, etc

Tags: doxygen

I want to create some alias that that internally creates `\struct` command that refers to some specific struct and adds some additional commands:

```
ALIASES += "thing{2}=\struct \2 \n \n \xrefitem thingList\"\" \"List of Things\" \2  this thing belongs to that \ref \1"
```

the alias is invoked in some normal doxy-comment:

```
/**
 *
 * \thing{SomeThing, SomeThingStruct}
 *
 * \brief ..sdfsdf
 */
typedef struct sSomeTag SomeThingStruct;
```

It mainly does that it should and also the xrefitem list is generated correctly, but i get the error:

```
warning: the name `\_linebr' supplied as the argument of the \class, \struct, \union, or \include command is not an input file
```

because it interprets the `\n` in the alias as second argument to the `\struct` keyword

How can i define my alias that it does not produce this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation about ALIASES in the doxygen documentation.

A few points directly from the documentation:

> ALIASES This tag can be used to specify a number of aliases that act
>   as commands in the documentation. An alias has the form: name=value
>   For example adding "sideeffect=@par Side Effects:\n" will allow you to
>   put the command \sideeffect (or @sideeffect) in the documentation,
>   which will result in a user-defined paragraph with heading "Side
>   Effects:". You can put \n's in the value part of an alias to insert
>   newlines (in the resulting output). You can put ^^ in the value part
>   of an alias to insert a newline as if a physical newline was in the
>   original file.

- We see here the usage of the equal sign (=)  (corrected in the mean time, had been forgotten during copying)
- the use of upper case <-> lowercase (you should now have a message: `warning: Found unknown command`\thing'` (corrected in the mean time)
- usage of `\n` might be `^^`

SO the alias should read:

`ALIASES += thing{2}="\struct \2 ^^ ^^ \xrefitem thingList\"\" \"List of Things\" \2  this thing belongs to that \ref \1"`

Comment: sry the equal sign was lost during copying.
But I overlooked the `^^` thing. Thank you for pointing me at this.